# Reversible shuffling a int array in java

Tags: java, arrays, shuffle, steganography

I have a int array of considerably large size. I need to shuffle the array completely using a key. I should be able to obtain the original array using the same key. I searched for any shuffle algorithms but the one i found like Fisher Yates does not use a key.

The int array is pixel values of a image. I need to hide data into it. So hiding data after shuffling the array enables accessing of data only if one have the key.

Comment: You can use Fisher Yates for this, as explained in http://stackoverflow.com/a/3542000/367273 -- BTW, that was the top match on Google for "reversible shuffle".

Answer (score 2):

Fisher-Yates uses a pseudo-random number generator, which you can seed using a key (look for cryptographic PRNGs). To reverse the process, shuffle an array of indices [0, *n*) using the same key, then perform a reverse shuffle.

Comment: this is what i came up with `for (int i=0; i < data.length; i++) {

           j = (j +  key[i % key.length]) % data.length;
            tmp = data[i];
            data[i] = data[j];
            data[j] = tmp;
        }` 
its shuffling the array but cant get the original back.

Comment: can you please replay.