# Character Shuffling and Re-Arranging in c#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

In my one application i want to shuffle string contents and in another application if i pass this shuffled string as input then that application has to return original string value.Is there any method is available to do this in dotnet plateform?

Comment: do you what to do some thing like Fisher–Yates shuffle?

Comment: where is the code you have already done?

Comment: by "application", do you mean "restful services" ?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? Use encryption/decryption methods.

Comment: @ShadowWizard that i am already doing..But for security we are going to do this one

Comment: Shuffle is the wrong term then. By definition it means "change the order **randomly**" so it's not meant to be reversible.

Comment: Heard of cryptography?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) algorithm.

> it is an algorithm for generating a random permutation of a finite
>   set—in plain terms, for randomly shuffling the set.

The basic method given for generating a random permutation of the numbers 1–N goes as follows:

1. Write down the numbers from 1 to N.
2. Pick a random number k between one and the number of unstruck
   numbers remaining (inclusive).
3. Counting from the low end, strike out the kth number not yet struck
   out, and write it down elsewhere.
4. Repeat from step 2 until all the numbers have been struck out.
5. The sequence of numbers written down in step 3 is now a random
   permutation of the original numbers.

there is an example : [shuffle algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541378/reversible-shuffle-algorithm-using-a-key)

and good one [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/the-danger-of-naivete.html)

Comment: @ Praveen Kumar: accept as answer if it is helfull:D

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not out of the box, but create yourself a `struct`

```
struct ShuffleChar{
    char c;
    int index;
}
```

and when you shuffle your letters, assign each letter an `index` so you can put them together again. Remember, a `string` only makes sense if the letters are in the correct order, changing that order will destroy that information and with high probability you cannot restore it...

Comment: ok..then how to re-arrange it?

Comment: Like I told you in my answer, try to preserve the information somehow. You can't recreate the original string once you shuffled it, without keeping any information about its origin