# is modern version of the Fisher–Yates shuffle irreversible (i.e. Durstenfeld's version)?

Tags: sorting, shuffle, oneway

1) Original version of Fisher–Yates shuffle is reversible (see: [Reversible shuffle algorithm using a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541378/reversible-shuffle-algorithm-using-a-key)) but my question is regarding modern version of the Fisher–Yates shuffle i.e. Durstenfeld's versionm -

Given shuffled set S' and random numbers set R (used in shuffling set S to S')

Is this shuffle reversible or irreversible?

2) Shuffling set S using random numbers set R by Sorting algorithm to produce shuffled set S'

Given shuffled set S' and random numbers R (used in shuffling set S to S' by sorting method)

Is this shuffle reversible or irreversible?

Please explain.

Comment: For (1), I don't see how the linked answer doesn't apply directly to the Durstenfeld's version.