# Unshuffle an array of int/char

Tags: c++, arrays, shuffle

To shuffle the chars of the string `st`, I use `std::shuffle` and a random number generator, which is fed by a known seed. This is part of an encoder that, for simplicity, just shuffles the input.

The shuffled data is going to be sent to a decoder. At that side we don't have access to the original input, but the shuffled one.

How can I **Unshuffle** the string `shuffledSt`, using the same random number generator and the same seed, until I can obtain the original string `st`?

```
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string st = "asdfgh";
    int seed = 1000;
    
    std::shuffle(st.begin(), st.end(), std::default_random_engine(seed));
    std::cerr << st << '\n';

    std::string shuffledSt = st;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Unshuffle"? Do you mean "sort", or do you mean "magically restore the original string, no matter what it looked like"? Or is the actual problem that you really want a shuffled _copy_ of `st` rather than modifying it?

Comment: `default_random_engine` is implementation defined, so you cannot do so portably. **If** you knew which type of random engine it was using, and if it were invertable (for example a linear congruent generator) then you could implement an "unshuffle" but you'd also need to know the implementation of `std::shuffle` to try to invert that process too. So long story short, probably not possible.

Comment: I don't believe [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) is easily reversible. Any solution will likely be implementation defined at best. You could instead shuffle a known sequence of unique values and compare the result with the original to know how the elements were shuffled. For example, shuffle the sequence `0, 1, 2, ..., n`.

Comment: You could use a loop to keep shuffling until you get something that is equal to the original. Of course, this is not efficient for large strings...

Comment: Though `std::shuffle` is implementation-defined, it has an implementation that is equivalent to Fisher-Yates shuffle.  And though `std::default_random_engine` is also implementation-defined, you can use it and the known seed to regenerate the shuffle order used in Fisher-Yates, then reverse the swaps manually.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541378/reversible-shuffle-algorithm-using-a-key.

Comment: why do you want to do this? Whatever you want to do with the unshuffled one, why dont you do it with the original string?

Comment: if this is of purely academic interest, I have no idea how to do it, for anything else simply use `unshuffled = st`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reversible shuffle algorithm using a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541378/reversible-shuffle-algorithm-using-a-key)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest following algorithm

- Generate a vector `indices` with `std::iota` of `st.size()` elements.
- Shuffle that vector with the same engine with the same seed.
- While looping over the shuffled vector, generate a new string `result` where `result[indices[i]] = st[i]`