# How to Encrypt & Decrypt Order of Array in Php

Tags: php, arrays, encryption

I want to encrypt order with key in Php. I mean i have an array like this:

```
$arr=[5,"a","li",10];
$key="random";

$newOrder=encryptArr($arr,$key);   // [10,"li",5,"a"]

$original=decryptArr($newOrder,$key); //[5,"a","li",10]
```

Comment: Hi, use https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sodium.php

Comment: which function should i usE?

Comment: It seems you are looking for some sort of reversible shuffle. This might be related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541378/reversible-shuffle-algorithm-using-a-key

Comment: And what's your question about this? What have you tried to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve expected result by implementing our own shuffle, that uses random numbers derived from a predetermined seed, generated from our key.

```
function encryptArr(array $input, string $key): array
{
    $seed = makeSeed($key);
    $swaps = generateSwaps(count($input), $seed);

    return swapElements($input, $swaps);
}

function decryptArr(array $input, string $key): array
{
    $seed = makeSeed($key);
    $swaps = generateSwaps(count($input), $seed);
    // If we used the same seed when "encrypting",
    // then all we have to do is swap the shuffled array in reverse order.
    $swaps = array_reverse($swaps);

    return swapElements($input, $swaps);
}


/**
 * Helper function that converts string key into an int
 * by calculating crc32 polynomial from the string
 */
function makeSeed(string $key): int
{
    return crc32($key);
}

/**
 * We are using a predetermined $seed to generate a pairs of random numbers from 0 to $length-1
 * Eg. [[0, 0], [1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 3]]
 *
 */
function generateSwaps(int $length, int $seed): array
{
    $swaps = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        mt_srand($seed+$i);
        $random_index = mt_rand(0, $length-1);
        $swaps[] = [$i, $random_index];
    }

    return $swaps;
}

function swapElements(array $input, array $swaps): array
{
    foreach ($swaps as $swap) {
        $tmp = $input[$swap[0]];
        $input[$swap[0]] = $input[$swap[1]];
        $input[$swap[1]] = $tmp;
    }

    return $input;
}

$arr=[5,"a","li",10];
$key="test";

$newOrder=encryptArr($arr,$key);
print_r($newOrder);

$original=decryptArr($newOrder,$key);
print_r($original);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 10
    [2] => a
    [3] => li
)
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => a
    [2] => li
    [3] => 10
)
```

Comment: Maybe we should improve makeSeed function. With current function "test" and "estt" will produce same order and we can decrypt order with any word that contain those chars "tets,etst" etc...

Comment: You are correct. Noticed that too, after posting the answer. Improved the makeSeed method.